# When an old iPhone 3 can connect to WiFi but not associated with a Cell Phone carrier, can it still send files?

Tags: wifi, iphone

I have an old iPhone 3 that was using AT&T as the phone carrier.  But since June 2010, I started using the iPhone 4 and that iPhone 3 has no phone carrier any more.

It connects to my home network using WiFi.  But when I try to send my old Notes written on the iPhone 3 by email or view weather or stock data, it can't access the network.

Is it true that an iPhone 3 that has no phone carrier won't be able to use the WiFi to send or receive data?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you switch to a new iPhone, the old iPhone will still be able to access data over WiFi, just not the 3G network.

Comment: turns out it is a DHCP problem: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35210/my-iphone-3g-wont-receive-data-using-wifi