# How to move iPhone 3's Notes, Voice Memo to a computer before giving it away?

Tags: iphone

I am giving away an iPhone 3 to a friend, and I can move all the photos and videos to a computer by copying the DCIM folder of the iPhone 3 (just like a USB flash drive or digital camera).

But I think the only other things are the Notes and the Voice Memos.  How can they be moved to the computer?  (I have been using the iPhone 4 for 1.5 years, so backing up the content of the iPhone 3 and restoring to iPhone 4 is not an option, I think, as it will wipe out my iPhone 4's content).

I know we can sync Voice Memos using iTunes, but I don't even have the computer that sync with the iPhone 3 any more, and it said that if I sync with any other computer, the content of the iPhone 3 will be replaced by the iTunes library on this new computer.  Can it still work?  As long as it doesn't remove those Voice Memos and still can move them to the new computer.

How about the Notes?  Is there a way?  I was going to email it... (not a perfect solution), but found that even though it connects to WiFi, but without a cell phone carrier any more, I can't send or receive data through WiFi either (see this related question posted by me:  [When an old iPhone 3 can connect to WiFi but not associated with a Cell Phone carrier, can it still send files?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35191/when-an-old-iphone-3-can-connect-to-wifi-but-not-associated-with-a-cell-phone-ca) ) Is it true?  Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting a new iPhone?  Back up the old one, wipe it and sell it.  When you get the new one, you can restore your backup to the new phone.

Comment: is it true that I can even buy an iPhone 3GS from eBay and restore the iPhone 3 data to that phone?  Are there multiple copies of backup of the iPhone 3 and how to choose which copy to use?  Can one backup restore to multiple phones too?