# My iPhone 3G won't receive data (using WiFi)

Tags: iphone

I have an older iPhone 3G and the cell phone carrier is no longer available.  It can connect to my WiFi, but the IP Address is showing as `192.254.xxx.xxx` and subnet mask as `255.255.0.0`, and no data can be sent or received.

If I compare the numbers with my iPhone 4S that can send or receive data, the IP Address is showing as `192.168.1.xx` (a local IP) and subnet mask showing as `255.255.255.0`.  Is there a way to make the iPhone 3G work like that and send and receive data?

Comment: Please include the correct model of phone (I've edited your other post). You are speaking about the iPhone 3G (not the 3GS). There is no such thing as an iPhone 3. Please be as clear as possible; you'll find more help that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that the device was unable to get an IP address via DHCP. The router may need to be rebooted itself, or it may not be set up to hand out IP information via DHCP and your iPhone will have to be set up statically. Check with the administrator of that wifi network for exact details. If it's your own, double check DHCP is enabled for your router, and if so, perform a hard reboot of the device.

Additionally, it never hurts to reboot your iPhone as well.

Should the problems persist, there may be a problem with the phone software or hardware. Restore the operating system on the phone, and try again. Should it still fail, my suggestion would be to take it to some Apple authorized repair depot for diagnostics.

Comment: This definitely sounds like a DHCP problem. You could also try going to the WiFi settings on the iPhone and manually putting in an unused address from your 192.168.1.X subnet.